# How to access the last return value in bash?

Tags: bash

Simple scenario: I'm looking for a `wsdl` file lost in the middle of a project.

```
$ find -name '*.wsdl'
./some/very/very/long/way/to/some/lost/directory/filename.wsdl
```

Now that I know where it is, I want to do something with this file, say edit it.  Instead of copy/pasting the path behind my command, is it possible to use the path returned by `find` earlier ?  Just like it's possible to access the last argument you've typed with `!$` or you last command with `!!`.
I've read that it was possible with `$?`, but it only returns me an error: `0: command not found`

```
$ echo $?
0: command not found
```

Comment: This is not the return value, it's the output!

Comment: To elaborate, the "return value" is always a number. Usually 0 means success, and non-zero means some kind of failure. The string (or text) that the command spits out is referred to as its "output", not its "return value".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Run the command in the command substitution:

```
output=$(find -name '*.wsdl')
```

The output is now stored in the `output` variable which you can use as many times as you like, with the following command:

```
echo "$output"
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer. $? is.

Comment: @mcmlxxxiii: `$?` doesn't contain the paths.

Comment: My apologies, I was confused by the misuse of the term `return` in the question. Your answer is absolutely correct for the above question.

Comment: `$?` contains the exit status of the last command

Comment: This was the answer that _I_ was looking for. I'm interested in the output of the previous command not the success/fail return value. So thank you!

Comment: usage example with conditional: `if result=$(sudo -Hu $innerUser -i -- sh -c "$cmd"); then…` – so yes, the if works as far as booleaness goes, and I do get the `$result` :)

Comment: @mcmlxxxiii Then you should delete your comments, they're very misleading currently.

Answer (score 101):

There is no special bash variable for that.

`$?` contains the exit code of the last command (0 = success, >0 = error-code)

You can use the output of `find` with the `-exec` flag, like this:

```
 find -name  '*.wsdl' -exec emacs {} \;
```

The `{}` is replaced with the file name found by `find`. This would execute the command for every found file. If you want to execute a command with all found files as arguments use a `+` at teh end like this:

```
  find -name '*.wsdl' -exec emacs {} +
```

This would open one emacs instance with all found .wsdl files opened in it.

A more general solution is to store the output in a variable:

```
result=$(find -name '*.wsdl')
emacs $result
```

This works with all commands, not just find. Though you might also use `xargs`:

```
  find -name '*.wsdl' | xargs emacs {}
```

Comment: Is it possible `$?` to return exit code of other command? e.g. ping 1.1.1.1 -w 10; return $?

Comment: `$?` contains the exit code of the previous command, whatever that is. So, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 64):

Here's a quick hack that should do what you want with minimal keystrokes, if you don't mind that the last command is executed twice.

Use backtick, ala:

`` `!!` ``

e.g.

```
$ find . -name HardToFind.txt
some/crazy/path/to/HardToFind.txt
$ vim `!!`
```

*edit: I see the above linked "possibly duped" question also contains this answer. still relevant directly to this one, so leaving it, but sorry for the dupe.

Comment: Very clever. I think this should be the accepted answer as it solves the most common case of not knowing you need the output until you've already run the command.

Comment: I agree, this is what I came here looking for. Doing anything on the previous line defeats my purpose, to retroactively decide I want to do something with the last returned value. (Checkout a branch I found via `git br | grep` in my case)

Comment: One of my favourites, this is! Think I do this on a day-to-day basis.

Comment: I think this is very clever that you can do that, but not sure how useful it really is. Is typing `!!` is that much easier than pressing the up key? And then you can still see your command. If running the command again is acceptable, I think just pressing up is just as easy (and a little more understandable and transparent),

Answer (score 0):

`` `!!` `` is a great solution, but if you want to be even quicker you could use aliases.

Unfortunately it won't work:

```
~$ alias test='echo `!!`'
~$ test
zsh: command not found: !!
```

So instead use `` `fc -e -` ``
 Example aliases I use:

copy output:

```
alias co='echo `fc -e -` | xclip -in -selection clipboard'
```

open with vim; if output has many lines, opens all of them in tabs:

```
alias vo='vim -p `fc -e -`'
```